# How to conditionally update a enum column value based on its current value in Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

Say I have a db schema as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE letter_enum AS ENUM ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');

CREATE TABLE foo(
  id int,
  letter letter_enum
);
```

I want to create a procedure such that:

- accepts id and letter
- updates the given id's letter conditionally such that:

1. for A, allows updates A -> B, A -> C, disallows A -> D
2. for B, allows updates B -> D, disallows B -> A, B -> C
3. for C, allows updates C -> D, disallows all other
4. for D, disallows all for D -> *

The reason why there is no pattern between update rules is that, my actual case allows only particular state changes regardless of their showing order. That's why I wanted to simulate the actual case by providing some dummy rules between letter change rules. Thus answers can be explanatory.

I tried to get a query working by MAX/MINs but enum type did restrict me so badly. Also, other questions on SOF are not covering enum type or they rely on the enum definition order. That is where my question differs from others. Thanks in advance.

Comment: write a before update trigger this is to complex for a constraint

Comment: What happens if the procedure is called with something that doesn't match your conditions? Should it silently do nothing, or should an error be thrown?

Comment: @EdmCoff should produce an error, and more specifically, I will handle that error at backend service. So this will be a user request to update enum in the first place.

Comment: I see you accepted the answer using a trigger, but just want to point out that this is slightly different than your question. The trigger will apply to any update on the table, whereas your question seems to imply you only want it to affect updates done using a particular procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a trigger for that. Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION letter_check() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
        IF OLD.letter != NEW.letter THEN
                IF OLD.letter='A' AND NEW.letter IN ('B', 'C') THEN
                        RETURN NEW;
                ELSIF OLD.letter='B' AND NEW.letter='D' THEN
                        RETURN NEW;
                ELSIF OLD.letter='C' AND NEW.letter='D' THEN
                        RETURN NEW;
                end if;
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'Changing letter from % to % is not allowed!', OLD.letter, NEW.letter;
        ELSE
                RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_letter_check BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION letter_check();
```

Then:

```
=> INSERT INTO foo(id, letter) VALUES (1, 'A');
UPDATE foo SET letter='D' WHERE id=1;
ERROR:  Changing letter from A to D is not allowed!
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function letter_check() line 11 at RAISE

=> UPDATE foo SET letter='B' WHERE id=1;
UPDATE 1
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. As a new postgres user let me ask a detail also: should I consider any possible race condition when using triggers? Say concurrent updates are taking place on a letter value. Does this trigger need any explicit isolation level set? Or an ordinary UPDATE is fine?

Comment: There's no danger of any race condition or any other parallelism interference added with this kind of trigger, as it does not execute any queries.